# How to save multiple lines (strings) from a rich edit into an array of string?

Tags: delphi

I don't know if it works or not, because I can't use "trace into". When I try to display the array values back in the `TRichEdit` using a `for` loop after clearing it, nothing gets displayed, it just turns blank.

```pascal
procedure TfrmEncryption.sedOffsetClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  K : integer;
begin
  for K := 1 to 26 do
  begin
    arrOffset[K] := redOutOffset.Lines.Strings[K];
  end;

  redOutOffset.Clear;

  for K := 1 to 26 do
  begin
    redOutOffset.Lines.Strings[K] := arrOffset[K];
  end;
end;
```

Comment: As an addition to @RemyLebeau's answer below, you don't have to use `Lines.Strings[]`. All TStrings descendents (which includes `TRichEdit.Lines') make `Strings` the default property, which means you can simply use `Lines[K]` instead. It's much easier to read and a lot fewer keystrokes to type. `TComboBox` and `TListBox` Items, which descend from `TStrings`, support default properties based on TStrings, so you can use `TComboBox.Items[K]` instead of `TComboBox.Items.Strings[K]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I don't know if it works or not, because I can't use "trace into".

Make sure you have "Use debug dcus" enabled in the Project Options. Then you should be able to step into the VCL's source code with the debugger at runtime.

> When I try to display the array values back in the `TRichEdit` using a `for` loop after clearing it, nothing gets displayed, it just turns blank.

After you `Clear()` the RichEdit, you can't index into its `Strings[]` anymore, since there is no more data. You will have to use `Lines.Add()` instead of `Lines.Strings[K]`, eg:

```pascal
redOutOffset.Lines.BeginUpdate;
try
  redOutOffset.Clear;

  for K := 1 to 26 do
  begin
    redOutOffset.Lines.Add(arrOffset[K]);
  end;
finally
  redOutOffset.Lines.EndUpdate;
end;
```